# Why is MVC stateless - How to explain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

While explaining concepts of ASP.NET MVC to my students

> MVC is stateless. It is built on top of another stateless
>   protocol - HTTP and HTTPS

But one student interrupted and asked,

> You tell that the MVC is stateless
>
> Stateless protocol never cares if the response comes back or not from
>   the server. But, in ASP.NET MVC framework, you make a request and wait
>   for the response. Since you wait for the response, it should be called
>   as a stateful service. How come you are calling it a stateless service
>   then?

I really got stuck up and wondered what to answer to this question.

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't know MVC was a protocol.

Comment: @Juhana: Correct. Removed that word :) Yup, there is a difference between `framework` and `protocol`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MVC is not stateless, HTTP is.

HTTP being stateless doesn't mean it is fire and forget. The client does wait for the response. It is stateless in the sense that two successive requests have no relation whatsoever.

State can be emulated using sessions, for example using cookies.

Comment: HTTP server is stateless, HTTP client never was.

Comment: @deerchao what do you mean?

Comment: For example, cookie must be remembered by client, not server.

Comment: When using sessions, the server also maintains a state.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thank you. Nice explanation. +1 for the second line

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't think that's necessary. Consider a server returns how many times the client has visited it, all it has to do is parse the previous request count stored in cookie, plus one, and send a new cookie back.

Answer (score 7):

The assertion in the question, purported by the other student it wrong. A [stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) like HTTP sure *does* care if it gets (or never gets) a response!

> [A stateless protocol] treats each request as an independent transaction that is unrelated to any previous request so that the communication consists of **independent *pairs* of request and response**.

Of course, MVC isn't even a protocol .. but the same notion can be extended. It is "stateless" insofar as all the information is encoded in the request and response as a "pair". In practice, most usages are not truly stateless.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is not a protocol is a software architectular pattern.

On the other hand, HTTP is a protocol.

In nowadays the MVC pattern is very popular among many web frameworks. These web frameworks and the rest of other web frameworks are used for the development of web applications. 
In the context of web applications HTTP is an application protocol *that is used from browsers for their communication* with the servers that host web applications.

Indeed the nature of HTTP is stateless. There isn't anywhere in HTTP the concept of `state`. For this reason, in many web frameworks, there are different ways through which we try to implement the concept of `state`. For instance in `ASP.NET Web Forms` the `ViewState` was developed for this reason.

That being said, MVC has nothing to do with the stateless nature of HTTP.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you're confusing MVC the pattern with ASP.NET MVC the framework.

Comment: @Juhana I am just referred to the MVC as a pattern and not for it's use by ASP.NET, which is resulted in ASP.NET MVC. For that reason I used the phrase Web Frameworks instead of referring to a specific one, like ASP.NET MVC, Djagno, RoR and so on.

Comment: My point is that your answer explains why MVC the pattern is or is not stateless, but the question isn't about MVC the pattern at all. The OP uses "MVC" as a shorthand for "ASP.NET MVC framework".

Comment: @Juhana yeah I got your point. It might be my fault, but I tried to be more general since that's not a problem specific to ASP.NET MVC as it is stated in the question. Thank you for you comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind, that there are a lot of different implementations of the concept of a model-view-controler architecture. There is no "correct" MVC.  ASP.NET MVC cannot be is not a "perfect" implementation of the model-view-controler pattern!

---

Otherwise of thinking of stateful/stateless MVC. MVC can be understood by thinking of responsibilities:

The View is not allowed to change the state of the model directly - only through the Controller. The view can still have some direct access to the Model although only for viewing (or by having a copy that isn't the official Model).

The Model should live in its own universe and not have any reference to controllers or to views.

The Controller controls the state and access to the Model.

---

How they all interact with each other, can be implemented very differently (based on the platform for example) ...