# Run while(true) Loop on HTTP Request in .NET Framework MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My goal is to have an HTTP request initiate a While(true) loop, until another request comes. When a second request comes, I want the first While(true) loop to be cancelled and a second one with different content to be run. My problem is I'm unsure of the best way to approach this. I've tried using Threads, Tasks, even putting the while(true) loops in my Controller (which I later found is really bad practice since controller objects are created on the fly), putting them in my model, etc.

The issue I encounter time and time again is that the while(true) loop doesn't stop. I can't get it to stop, whether by interrupting a thread, changing a boolean variable. I think this comes from a high-level misunderstanding I have about the lifecycle of requests and MVC objects.

Specifically, I am trying to start a while(true) loop that will write a specific lighting sequence to LED strips (i.e. Rainbow themed, Jungle themed, carousel, etc.). To iterate over different colors and write continuously, I need a while(true) to loop until interrupted. Conceptually this is what I have in mind:

[image]

Different things I've tried in terms of code are as follow:

1. Running the task from the controller (Not going for this anymore -- while loop never ends and is apparently bad practice).

```cs
        [Route("[controller]/Rainbow")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void Rainbow([FromBody] Sequence sequence)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sequence called: " + sequence.sequence);

            cancelSequence.Cancel();  // cancel all other tasks
            cancelSequence = new CancellationTokenSource();  // create new token

            int rainbowColorOffset = 0;
            var rainbowColors = new List<Color>
            {
                Color.Red,
                Color.DarkOrange,
                Color.Yellow,
                Color.Green,
                Color.Blue,
                Color.Purple,
                Color.DeepPink
            };
            rainbow = new Task(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Rainbow running");
                    cancelSequence.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    for (var i = 0; i < ledCount; i++)
                    {
                        var colorIndex = (i + rainbowColorOffset) % rainbowColors.Count;
                        //ledStrip.SetSpecificLed(i, colors[colorIndex]);
                    }
                    rainbowColorOffset = (rainbowColorOffset + 1) % rainbowColors.Count;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }, cancelSequence.Token);
            rainbow.Start();  // start task until another task cancels it via cancellation token
        }
        }
```

2. Calling the task from the model, and having the controller initiate it. Also results in infinite looping, and I can't stop the task from looping.

- Controller:

```cs
        // Rainbow function. First initializes LED strip, then loops while performing action.
        public void Rainbow()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Rainbow Sequence Called");
            // run task in model
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var settings = LedInit();
                using (var rpi = new WS281x(settings))
                {
                    int colorOffset = 0;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        var colors = GetRainbowColors();
                        for (var i = 0; i < ledCount; i++)
                        {
                            var colorIndex = (i + colorOffset) % colors.Count;
                            rpi.SetLed(i, colors[colorIndex]);
                        }
                        rpi.Render();
                        colorOffset = (colorOffset + 1) % colors.Count;
                        Task.Delay(500);
                    }
                }
            }).Wait();
        }
```

I'm starting to believe I may need to rethink my entire design. Maybe I need a service to execute the different lighting sequences? Maybe it's simpler and I'm overcomplicating things? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounters a similar problem, my solution was to use a static class with static members to perform the threading. Instead of dynamically creating objects upon HTTP requests, I'd create an object of the static class to interact with the same variables. I made all functions and data members static, and I was then able to start and stop threads properly.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. Each HTTP request does not know about the previous request. It's a fire and forget notion in HTTP world. So if you are redirecting to one page to another page, then you have to maintain your data by using Cookies, Query String, Session, ViewBag or TempData or better yet persist it on the database.

More explanation regarding HTTP Statelessness can be found here:

[Why is MVC stateless - How to explain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470065/why-is-mvc-stateless-how-to-explain)

So you cannot implement by waiting on the second request and interrupt the first/previous request, since every request is unique.

Comment: If the HTTP is stateless, that's okay. I just need a static state in the MVC chain so I can start and stop threads. I keep losing the threads I start, and am unable to interrupt them. Just not sure how to keep track of these threads in .NET